# Is there a rule distinguishing what kind of verbs can only take more/most?

Tags: verbs, comparatives, superlative-degree

My theory is that dynamic verbs can take either more/most or better/best but the meaning will change.

> I sleep more than him.

This means I sleep longer hours (quantity) than him.

> I sleep better than him.

This means my sleep is of better quality than his.

Stative verbs can only take more/most.

> I need water more than food.

Notice that you can't say:

> I need water better than food.

But if I'm right, why can you say:

> I know her better than you.

How can the quality of your knowing be good?

Comment: We speak of knowing a person or place _well_ when we are closely acquainted with them/it. It's 'just the way we say it'.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting That is indeed the best explanation.  Isn't one way of explaining to look at it in terms of whether whatever-it-is is capable of measurement/comparison in terms of size, speed, quality, degree, intensity...?  Some of these comparisons, especially personal ones, will be highly subjective.  You could ask:  "what would count as a good reason for disagreeing?  It could be amount of contact, yes; or that you know something very significant about them that I don't know:  that they had done/were doing something amazingly good/clever or bad/stupid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no such rule. I don't think that making your own classifications will get you anywhere. English is a very idiomatic language and rules have exceptions and exceptions have their own exceptions, because *that's what we say in English*.

It is idiomatic to say that you *[know someone/something (full) well](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know-full-well)* and this is why we have ***[well known](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well-known)***, not **much known*, but ***much needed** advice*.

***Feel*** is normally a stative verb, but when used [*punctually*](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/1076/file/Engelberg_The_magic_of_the_moment_1999.pdf), it is clearly idiomatic to say *Are you feeling any **better**?*

In less common contexts you will find:

> I feel it in my lungs, every time they clutch my breath, I start to ***feel** it **more***. (*[I swapped... heartbreak for more heartbreak](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/I_swapped_liqueur_for_coffee_and_heartbr/PmZ1CAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22feel%20it%20more%22&pg=PT30&printsec=frontcover)*, Jodie Matthews)

The two usages have different meanings, but you can see that in its non-stative use, *feel* can take both *better* and *more*.

It is better to take every verb on its own and get to know its area of usage by... usage.